# Why is my result duplicated when using subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Please bear in mind that I am very new to MySQL.

I am stuck when I try to select a set of results.

```
select A.userNum from tableOne A, tableTwo B where A.userNum!=B.userNum;
```

(Table A contains userNum and phone number of a user. Table B contains addressbook of a user.)

The ResultSet contains multiple sets of similar results. Each result omits one userNum that I specified in the where clause. (see the end of this question)

How can I get ResultSet that only contains one result with fulfilling "where A.userNum!=B.userNum" clause?

### Here's a specific case that I am having trouble.

Say I have two tables, users and addressbook.

Table 'adressbook' is basically an address book. Table 'users' is a table containing an user's phone number.

I created tables. For simplicity, the 'userNum' and 'phone' number is same in 'users' table.

```
create table users (
    userNum int,
    phone char(11)
);
insert into users values (1,'1');
insert into users values (2,'2');
insert into users values (3,'3');
insert into users values (4,'4');
insert into users values (5,'5');
insert into users values (6,'6');
insert into users values (7,'7');
insert into users values (8,'8');
insert into users values (9,'9');
insert into users values (10,'10');
```

---

```
create table addressbook (
    userNum int,
    phone char(11)
);
insert into addressbook values(1,'2');
insert into addressbook values(1,'3');
insert into addressbook values(2,'3');
insert into addressbook values(3,'4');
insert into addressbook values(5,'7');
insert into addressbook values(5,'8');
insert into addressbook values(6,'7');
insert into addressbook values(7,'8');
insert into addressbook values(7,'9');
insert into addressbook values(9,'10');
```

---

Next, I will find out 'userNum' of my friend's friend. Let's say I am userNum 1.

First, I found the 'userNum' of my friend.

```
select A.userNum from users A, addressbook B where B.userNum=1 and B.phone=A.phone;
```

then using this query, I found the 'userNum' of my friend's friend.

```
select A.userNum from users A, addressbook B, (select A.userNum from users A, addressbook B where B.userNum=1 and B.phone=A.phone) C 
where C.userNum=B.userNum and A.phone=B.phone;
```

The result is 3,4. (Strange, the ResultSet here does not duplicate when I use subquery.)

---

The problem starts here.

Using the select statment above as the subquery B, I tried to get 'userNum' of people who's not a friend's friend of mine.

```
select A.userNum from users A, 
    (select A.userNum from users A, addressbook B, (select A.userNum from users A, addressbook B where B.userNum=1 and B.phone=A.phone) C where C.userNum=B.userNum and A.phone=B.phone) B 
    where A.userNum!=B.userNum;
```

The result

```
userNum
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

As you can see from the result, there are two sets of results. First result omits userNum 3, the second userNum 4.

How can I get one set of userNum that omits userNum 3,4?

Comment: Noob question... Am I using the term 'subquery' right in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select A.userNum from users A where A.userNum NOT IN  (select A.userNum from users A, addressbook B, (select A.userNum from users A, addressbook B where B.userNum=1 and B.phone=A.phone) C where C.userNum=B.userNum and A.phone=B.phone) ;
```