# How to refactor(or improve performance) a duplicated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database

(This is a follow up on this question: [Why is my result duplicated when using subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463398/why-is-my-result-duplicated-when-using-subquery))

How can I make something like this better?

```
(select * from tableOne A, tableTwo B where ~) union (select * from tableTwo)
```

### A specific case

***TableOne***

```
select A.userNum from users A, addressbook B where B.userNum=1 and B.phone=A.phone;
```

which returns with list of my friend's userNum.

The I use

***TableTwo***

```
select A.userNum from users A, addressbook B, 
(select A.userNum from users A, addressbook B where B.userNum=1 and B.phone=A.phone) C 
where C.userNum=B.userNum and A.phone=B.phone;
```

Which returns list of userNums of my Friend's friend. You can see that TableTwo uses TableOne as table C.

Then I want to get my friends' userNum and friends' friends' userNum like this.

***TableThree***

```
TableOne union TableTwo;
```

Finally, I will use TableThree to get userNums of people whose not a friend's friend of mine.

```
select A.userNum from users A where A.userNum NOT IN TableThree;
```

You can see that TableThree uses subquery TableOne twice in the query. I believe this is a bad idea as in bad refactoring and a bad performance.

Is there a better way to write this query?

Comment: Side note: tips to write better SQL CODE Tip 1 use useful aliases not A for table 1  B for table2 ... makes it really hard to understand your querys TIP 2 use the ANSI JOIN syntax..   TIP3 structure (newlines, tabs) your SQL so it's readable and not oneliners..  see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04034/4 what i mean this is much more readable vs your SQL

Comment: Does this query perform really bad on your system, and you want to optimise it ? Or do you only belive that it **may** perform poor, and it's only academic question ? In the first case, please provide the exact SQL code of the query together wiht explain plan and table structures and definition of existing indexes. In the latter case the question is rather subjective and it is hard to answer - in some cases UNION performs better than one big query with many OR conditions, but in other cases the opposite may be true.

Comment: @kordirko I think this is the first case. The time it takes for the last query(TableThree) is about 0.219 sec. Using the query(TableThree) as a subquery in the where caluse, I have to retrieve 100 records(I will edit my question later with what I am trying to do). This takes about 0.7 seconds. I don't know if this is normal for database with 10K rows. I will edit this question later with more information.